# Configuring Ubuntu Virtual machine network - behind proxy firewall

Tags: virtualbox

I have created a Ubuntu virtual machine on Windows 7 but not able to connect to internet.
Is it possible to provide the specific settings required to configure internet connections

Answer (score 0):

VirtualBox is funny sometimes about connecting to your network connection. Just make sure you are connected to the Internet and reboot or reset VirtualBox. When it boots up with a live network connection, it will recognize it and make it available to the virtual OS. No special settings are required, just one reboot.

After the reboot, you will be able to unplug and plug-in the network connection as much as you like and VirtualBox will recognize the changes just fine.

Comment: behind proxy...